# What is the advantage of having attributes in angularjs directive restricted to comments? Aren't comments stripped by the compiler?

Tags: angularjs, directive

What advantage does this provide you with in AngularJS?

```
<!-- directive: directive-name arguments -->
```

Comment: post your js code please

Comment: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/restrict/

Answer (score 2):

There is on advantages at all. Even more, [Papa Jhon suggests](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) to avoid this.

> When creating a directive that makes sense as a stand-alone element,
>   allow restrict E (custom element) and optionally restrict A (custom
>   attribute). Generally, if it could be its own control, E is
>   appropriate. General guideline is allow EA but lean towards
>   implementing as an element when it's stand-alone and as an attribute
>   when it enhances its existing DOM element.

And even more, there is a special [flag](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) in angular that disable this functionality and speed up compiling a bit.

So no advantages at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `restrict:"C"` it means class not comment

ex: `<div class="container"></div>`

js:

```
module.directive('container',function(){
   //do something
 })
```